# Laravel: Querying and accessing child objects in nested relationship with where clauses

Tags: laravel, nested, eloquent, relationships

I am trying to access the child objects of nested relationships that return many results from the parents object.

Let's say I have 4 models : Country - Provinces - Cities - Municipalities

Their relationships are as follows :

**Country Model**

```
class Country extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'countries';

   public function provinces()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('Province');
   }
}
```

**Province Model**

```
class Province extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'provinces';

   public function cities()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('City');
   }
   public function country()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('Country');
   }
}
```

**City Model**

```
class City extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'cities';

   public function municipalities()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('Municipality');
   }
   public function province()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('Province');
   }
}
```

**Municipality Model**

```
class Municipality extends Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'municipalities';

   public function cities()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('City');
   }
 }
```

Now what I am trying to do is get all municipalities in a given country that have a population over 9000 and are located in provinces that are considered West.

So far I have something like this :

```
   $country_id = 1;

   $country = Country::whereHas('provinces', function($query){
        $query->where('location', 'West');
        $query->whereHas('cities', function($query){ 
            $query->whereHas('municipalities', function($query){
                $query->where('population', '>', 9000);
            });            
        });
    })->find($country_id);
```

Now I can easily get the provinces with `$country->provinces` but I can't go any deeper than that.

EDIT1 : Fixing the belongsTo relationship as noticed by Jarek.

EDIT2: In addition to Jarek's answer, I wanted to share what I also found however Jarek's is probably the more proper method.

Instead of trying to go from top to bottom (Country -> Municipality) I decided to try the other way (Municipality -> Country) Here's how it works (and I tested it, also works)

```
          $municipalities = Municipality::where('population', '>', 9000)
            ->whereHas('city', function($q) use ($country_id){
                $q->whereHas('province', function($q) use ($country_id){
                    $q->where('location', 'West');
                    $q->whereHas('country', function($q) use ($country_id){
                          $q->where('id', $country_id);
                    });
                });
            })->get();
```

I have no idea if this is an actual proper way or if performance would be accepted but it seemed to do the trick for me however Jarek's answer looks more elegant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `Municipality`-`City` is probably `belongsTo`, not `hasMany` like in the paste.

Anyway you can use `hasManyThrough` relation to access far related collection:

```
Country - City
Province - Municipality
```

Unfortunately there is no relation for 3 level nesting, so you can't do this just like that.

---

Next, your code with `whereHas` does not limit `provinces` to `west` and `municipalities` to `9000+`, but only limits `countries` to those, that are related to them. In your case this means that result will be either `Country` (if its relations match these requirements) or `null` otherwise.

So if you really want to limit related collections, then you need this piece:

```
$country = Country::with(['provinces' => function($query){
    $query->where('location', 'West');
}, 'provinces.cities.municipalities' => function ($query){
    $query->where('population', '>', 9000);
}])->find($country_id);
```

This is applying eager loading constraints, and what it does is:

```
1. loads only West provinces for country with id 1
2. loads all the cities in these provinces
3. loads only 9k+ municipalities in these cities
```

Since you're not interested in cities, you could use `hasManyThrough` on the Province:

```
// Province model
public function municipalities()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Municipality', 'City');
}
```

then:

```
$country = Country::with(['provinces' => function($query){
    $query->where('location', 'West');
}, 'provinces.municipalities' => function ($query){
    $query->where('population', '>', 9000);
}])->find($country_id);
```

---

However in both cases you can't access the municipalities directly, but only like this:

```
// 1 classic
$country->provinces->first()->cities->first()->municipalities;
// 2 hasManyThrough
$country->provinces->first()->municipalities;
```

That being said, if you'd like to work with all those municipalities, you need this trick:

```
$country = Country::with(['provinces' => function($query){
    $query->where('location', 'West');
}, 'provinces.municipalities' => function ($query) use (&$municipalities) {

    // notice $municipalities is passed by reference to the closure
    // and the $query is executed using ->get()
    $municipalities = $query->where('population', '>', 9000)->get();
}])->find($country_id);
```

This will run additional query, but now all the municipalities are in single, flat collection, so it is very easy to work with. Otherwise you likely end up with a bunch of foreach loops.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for but couldn't figure it out. At the same time I also figured out another way to do it and it was to filter bottom up. I will update my question to reflect what I have found.

Comment: I also wanted to note that it is interesting that you can only go 3 levels of nesting and now that I know, I can work around that.

Comment: Yes, you can do it the other way around using `whereHas`. This is a good way, just depends on your needs. Anyway I don't get what you mean by 3 levels of nesting?